# Arduino Prototype on Breadboard: "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"

Tags: serial, programming, sketch, prototype

I have created an arduino prototype using the exact instructions found on this page:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone

However, when I plug in the micro USB power supply and try to upload a program, here's the error I get:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
```

I have tried the following solutions, to no avail:
1) press the restart button (in a variety of ways and lengths of time)
2) Enable verbose output 
3) trying the different board types in the Arduino IDE
4) Checking the COM port

I have no idea what to do I've basically tried everything I could find, on this website and others.

I hope you guys can help! Thanks very much :)

Comment: Those instructions do seem to lack one vital bit: the connection between DTR on the USB board, through a 100nF capacitor, to the reset pin of the ATMega328P.

Comment: Thank you. So how would I make this connection, given that the reset pin of the ATMega is already connected to a momentary switch?

Comment: Just like I said. There's more than one hole in the breadboard...

Comment: I will give it a go, thanks. Just to confirm: 100nF = 100 x 10^-9 F?

Comment: Yes, but what does that matter? 100nF is 100nF or 0.1uF. No one works in F it is too big.

Comment: Either you don't have serial communication, your ATmega is not powered, fused, and clocked correctly, or it does not yet contain a bootloader of compatible configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pins connected to Tx and Rx while uploading the code , it worrked for me.
also include all the libraries currently used in your program.
Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Check for Baudrate, the Arduino Serial Terminal, and serial port terminal should exactly match.

Or either check your Rx and Tx pins for respective voltages
Either there may be problem related to power supply.
It is better you also mention the code